# фильтры вордпресс через отдельные страницы

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В каталоге товаров интернет-магазина есть фильтр по брендам, при выборе бренда ссылка приобретает такой вид /{Название категории}/?pwb-brand-filter={Название бренда}, а требуется чтобы был переход на отдельную страницу вида /{Название категории}/brand-is-{Название бренда}.

Сайт на вордпрессе, для магазина используется вукоммерс, а бренды реализованны через Perfect Brands for WooCommerce.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```php
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'rewrite_request_1474495', 20);

function rewrite_request_1474495(){
    // проверяем наличие префикса
    $brand_pos = strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/brand-is-');
    if($brand_pos === false){
        return;
    }

    // разбираем URL на части
    $url_parts = wp_parse_url($url);

    // разбираем PATH на части
    $url_path_parts = explode("/", $url_parts['path']);

    // извлекаем последний элемент PATH из массива и удаляем префикс
    $brand = str_replace('brand-is-', array_pop($url_path_parts));

    // склеиваем элементы PATH обратно
    $url_parts['path'] = implode("/", $url_path_parts);

    // добавляем параметр в массив
    $query_array = [
        'pwb-brand-filter' => htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($brand))
    ];

    // добавляем остальные параметры в массив
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $query_array[htmlspecialchars($key)] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value));
    }

    // помещаем новую строку параметров запроса в массив
    $url_parts['query'] = http_build_query($query_array);

    // склеиваем части URL и помещаем в REQUEST_URI
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = build_url($url_parts);

    // Помещаем значение бренда в массив $_GET, чтобы плагин мог его оттуда прочитать
    $_GET['pwb-brand-filter'] = $query_array['pwb-brand-filter'];
}

function build_url(array $parts) {
    return (isset($parts['scheme']) ? "{$parts['scheme']}:" : '') . 
        ((isset($parts['user']) || isset($parts['host'])) ? '//' : '') . 
        (isset($parts['user']) ? "{$parts['user']}" : '') . 
        (isset($parts['pass']) ? ":{$parts['pass']}" : '') . 
        (isset($parts['user']) ? '@' : '') . 
        (isset($parts['host']) ? "{$parts['host']}" : '') . 
        (isset($parts['port']) ? ":{$parts['port']}" : '') . 
        (isset($parts['path']) ? "{$parts['path']}" : '') . 
        (isset($parts['query']) ? "?{$parts['query']}" : '') . 
        (isset($parts['fragment']) ? "#{$parts['fragment']}" : '');
}
```